# How to reference element for create dynamic component in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular

```
<div *ngFor="let w of widgets">
    <div #elem [id]="w.componentName"></div>
</div>
```

I want to create dynamic component by reference attribute **[id]**.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a new component and embed into your `*ngFor` and passing the ID  into the new component through `@Input()`?

Comment: I had multiple component. But I create some component in my page because I get component name from database.
I use Gridstack library for manage layout. then finished I want to push component in element by attribute ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service :

```js
@Injectable()
export class WidgetService {
  
  getWidget(id) : IWidget {
    // return your constructed widget instead
    return {componentName : id};
  }
}
```

Now create a widget component that takes in ID and sends request to the above service to get widget :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'widget',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{data.componentName}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [WidgetService]
})
export class WidgetComponent implements OnInit{
  @Input() id: string;
          data: IWidget;
  constructor(private wService : WidgetService) {}
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.wService.getWidget(this.id);
  }
  
}
```

Using interface to pass information as widget interface here..

```js
export interface IWidget {
  componentName : string
}
```

Now modify your code to accept WidgetComponent inside *ngFor :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let w of widgets">
      <widget [id]="w.componentName"></widget>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  widgets:IWidget[];
  constructor() {
    this.widgets = [
      {componentName : "w1"},
      {componentName : "w2"},
      {componentName : "w3"}
      ]
  }
}
```